# moving object in multiple direction in corona

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I'm trying to move a rectangle on using `transition.to` when I finish the first transition I want to make another one but I don't want to move the object like what `transition.moveto` do. I want to transition the object on the X axis first then the Y axis. What I did is to make first transition and on its complete event listener I make the second one but what I get is just the first transition

```
    local square = display.newRect( 0, 0, 10, 10 )
    transition.to( square,{time=2000, x=100, transition=easing.inOutExpo,onComplete=completeListener} )
    local  function completeListener(  )
    print( "hi" )
    transition.to( square, {y=200,time=2000} )
    end
```

but the the second transition doesn't work -- it's like the listener function never got called.

Comment: Yes? Did this not work for you? You forgot the "question" in your question -- Edit: much better!

Comment: I can't seem to spot the problem. However you could potentially just delay the second transition with parameter delay = 2000. That way the second transition doesn't begin until the first one is completed. A bit of a work around though.

Comment: thx frozire your solution works but i looking for why oncomplete listener doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple rearrangement of the code solved it. This way the function is actually created, before we try to call it.

```
local square = display.newRect( 0, 0, 10, 10 )

local function completeListener()
transition.to(square, {time=2000,y=200} )
end

transition.to( square,{time=2000, x=100, transition=easing.inOutExpo,onComplete=completeListener} )
```